# Updating a java jframe

Tags: java, swing, concurrency, jtextarea, event-dispatch-thread

I am trying to update the text in a `jtextarea` stored in a class I created with the netbeans GUI tool.

In my server class I have the following code....

window is the name of the object instance

```
Message message = (Message) in.readObject();
window.addText(message.getMessage());
```

The `getMessage` meathod works and I can output text to the console using this method.

This is the code I have in the GUI class (window) to update the textarea:

```
public void addText(String txt)
{
    jTextArea1.append(txt);
    jTextArea2.append(txt);
    jTextArea1.updateUI();
    jTextArea1.revalidate();
    jTextArea1.validate();
    jTextArea2.updateUI();
    jTextArea2.revalidate();
    jTextArea2.validate();
}
```

However this isn't updating... the method is defiantly receiving the string as I have tried outputting to the console from there (with no problem).

Do I need to refresh the window somehow?

---

The full GUI class

```
 package hunterinstant;


public class Conversation extends javax.swing.JFrame implements Runnable {


    public Conversation() {
        initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTextArea1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTextArea2 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
        jTextArea1.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextArea1);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jTextArea2.setColumns(20);
        jTextArea2.setEditable(false);
        jTextArea2.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jTextArea2);

        jButton1.setText("Send");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane2)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 294, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 80, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 243, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1)
                    .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 29, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public void run() {
        /*
         * Set the Nimbus look and feel
         */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /*
         * If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the
         * default look and feel. For details see
         * http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Conversation.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Conversation.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Conversation.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Conversation.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /*
         * Create and display the form
         */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new Conversation().setVisible(true);
            }
        });


    }

    public void addText(String txt)
    {
        jTextArea1.append(txt);
        jTextArea2.append(txt);
        jTextArea1.updateUI();
        jTextArea1.revalidate();
        jTextArea1.validate();
        jTextArea2.updateUI();
        jTextArea2.revalidate();
        jTextArea2.validate();
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    // End of variables declaration
}
```

Comment: jtextarea.repaint is how you could update just the JTextArea, if you want to update everything then call panel.updateUI();

Comment: `append()` is all you need. If the text doesn't show up, it can mean that you're not add text to the correct window, or that you're doing it it from a thread which is not the event dispatch thread, or both. We need more details. Where does this window object come from, etc.

Comment: you have got issue with `Concurency in Swing`, in the case that works `jTextArea1.append(txt);` wrapped into `invokeLater`, then have look at `SwingWorker`, for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, btw here are a few examples about `SwingWorker` to `put/get Object` from/to `Socket`

Comment: The GUI class is not really helpful. What matters is from which thread the code updating the GUI is running, and how does this code gets a reference to the GUI. Add a trace to the constructor of the GUI to see if it's invoked more than once.

Comment: @John `updateUI` has nothing to do with refreshing the component, but advisers the component that the look and feel has changed.  While it will "refresh" a component, the method is time consuming and not recommended unless you are changing the look and feel at runtime (which is recommended any way)